# exec to pod using client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I am new to go and client-go :).

I saw this function where I can use it to send a command or exec to a pod with an interactive terminal. In the below, I need to know what parameters should I provide to call it from func main() as I can see it requires "config *restclient.Config" which I do not understand. Any example or a starting point ?

PS. I know how to create the clientset to authenticate using kubeconfig. just need to know what parameters this will require and how to call it from the main function.

```
package main

import (
    "io"

    v1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/scheme"
    restclient "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/remotecommand"
)

//ExecCmdExample exec command on specific pod and wait the command's output.
func ExecCmdExample(client kubernetes.Interface, config *restclient.Config, podName string,
    command string, stdin io.Reader, stdout io.Writer, stderr io.Writer) error {
    cmd := []string{
        "sh",
        "-c",
        command,
    }
    req := client.CoreV1().RESTClient().Post().Resource("pods").Name(podName).
        Namespace("default").SubResource("exec")
    option := &v1.PodExecOptions{
        Command: cmd,
        Stdin:   true,
        Stdout:  true,
        Stderr:  true,
        TTY:     true,
    }
    if stdin == nil {
        option.Stdin = false
    }
    req.VersionedParams(
        option,
        scheme.ParameterCodec,
    )
    exec, err := remotecommand.NewSPDYExecutor(config, "POST", req.URL())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = exec.Stream(remotecommand.StreamOptions{
        Stdin:  stdin,
        Stdout: stdout,
        Stderr: stderr,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to get the exit code of the remotely executed command?

Answer (score -2):

I was able to resolve this. the question can be closed.

Edit:

you can look at the code here:

https://github.com/mohatb/kubego

Comment: Please edit your answer to help people having the same question.